# crypto/sha1 not matching openssl command

Tags: go, openssl, sha

I'm trying to compute sha1, but the sha1 is not matching with the openssl command.

I compute the hash for an empty file like so on my Macbook :

```
$ touch test.txt
$ openssl sha1 -hex test.txt
SHA1(test.txt)= da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

And [here](http://play.golang.org/p/Yo2ETHQX3s) is the simple test code I have :

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "crypto/sha1"

func main() {
        hash := sha1.New()
        hash.Write([]byte{0x00})
        fmt.Printf("Hash got %x, expected da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", hash.Sum(nil))
}
```

Here is the output as you see the output does not match, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Hash got 5ba93c9db0cff93f52b521d7420e43f6eda2784f, expected da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

Comment: At what point do you feed `test.txt` content to sha1? Don't you just calculate sha1 of 0 byte?

Comment: Sorry - you said that test.txt is empty. But empty is probably different from single byte 0 content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Go code is computing the SHA of an input of length 1, with a value of `[ 0 ]`.

The `touch` command actually creates an empty file (zero length), so the equivalent Go code would be:

```
hash := sha1.New()
// hash.Write([]byte{}) 
data := hash.Sum(nil)
fmt.Printf("hash: %x", data)
```

The (commented) Write call above is a no-op.  [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/61klJgPHId)

Your test code does not actually seem to read from a file.  Anyway, per your request, here is what a full sha utility would look like in Go:

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/sha1"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        if len(os.Args) < 2 {
                fmt.Printf("usage: %s <file>\n", os.Args[0])
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        file := os.Args[1]

        f, err := os.Open(file)

        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        defer f.Close()

        hash := sha1.New()

        _, err = io.Copy(hash, f)

        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(nil))
}
```

Testing it out, I get:

```
$ touch test.txt
$ go run sha.go test.txt
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work for the 0 length input.In my code I'm actually reading from a file and writing directly to the hash and it doesn't match. Can you provide an example of reading from a file which matches the openssl command?

Comment: Thanks for your examples, my issue was stemming from another package.